# RadioGroup will not select when onChange is set that uses useState hook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a RadioGroup that works wonderfully. The minute I move that RadioGroup into its own function -- the "select" does not work. It's as if the components fails to re-render fully. This happens when I attach an `onChange` event that uses state hook. You can see here, radios 1 and 2 work well. Radios 3 and 4 do not.

[CodeSandbox Material UI RadioBox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-radiogroup-gx0r0?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.jsx)

Here's the component that I'm using. The RadioGroup that's NOT wrapped into a function works well. The one that is -- it does not "select". Meaning the black dot does not appear in the select radio button.

```
function Demo(props) {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));

    console.debug(`${event.target.name}: ${event.target.value}`);
  };

  const NotWorking = props => {
    return (
      <RadioGroup aria-label="two" name="two" row onChange={handleInputChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="3"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="3"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="4"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="4"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    );
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <RadioGroup aria-label="one" name="one" row onChange={handleInputChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="1"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="1"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="2"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="2"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
      <NotWorking />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: p.s. - both fire the handleInputChange event ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your wrapped component has to accept the `onChange` handler as a prop, together with `inputs`. Additionally you'd move it outside of parent component for better readability:

```
const NotWorking = props => {
    return (
      <RadioGroup aria-label="two" name="two" row onChange={props.onChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="3"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="3"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="4"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="4"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    );
  };


function Demo(props) {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));

    console.debug(`${event.target.name}: ${event.target.value}`);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <RadioGroup aria-label="one" name="one" row onChange={handleInputChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="1"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="1"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="2"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="2"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
      <NotWorking onChange={handleInputChange} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: I did as you suggested, see https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-radiogroup-gx0r0?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.jsx and the event does not fire ... but the radio box does render. But I need it to fire the event ...

Comment: What do you mean it does not fire? I can see the output in console.

Comment: I've added a a third component, exactly as you suggested. Moved it outside. Called it Clarity. Radio values are 5 and 6. If you look at the Console it does not fire the onChange event ...

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-radiogroup-gx0r0?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FDemo.jsx

Comment: Ah, sorry my bad, it'd be `onChange={props.onChange}` instead of `onChange={props.handleInputChange}` in `NotWorking` component. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually using your inputs anywhere. You need to specify the value. Otherwise you get an uncontrolled radio group (which should work in both cases but apparently doesn't for some reason I still haven't figured out).

However here's how you can get it to work **and** be able to tell what's selected by looking at the state:

```js
function Demo(props) {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});

  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist();
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    }));

    console.debug(`${event.target.name}: ${event.target.value}`);
  };

  const NotWorking = props => {
    return (
      <RadioGroup aria-label="two" name="two" value={inputs.two || ''} row onChange={handleInputChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="3"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="3"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="4"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="4"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
    );
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <RadioGroup aria-label="one" name="one" value={inputs.one || ''} row onChange={handleInputChange}>
        <FormControlLabel
          value="1"
          control={<Radio color="primary" />}
          label="1"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          value="2"
          control={<Radio />}
          label="2"
          labelPlacement="end"
        />
      </RadioGroup>
      <NotWorking />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-radiogroup-rnepu)

Comment: That works too. I've opened an MUI bug, which was closed due do it not being a bug. But the author (oliviertassinari) did say this: "Tip: new component instance => remount => reset of local state."

https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18237

Comment: Thanks, I ultimately went with the answer below as typing in onChange={props.onChange} is easier and less error prone than having to know the exact value to use in "inputs". Is it inputs.one, inputs.two? Easier to just type in onChange={props.onChange.}